# How to fix the list size in drop down button to a number and make it scrollable in flutter?

Tags: drop-down-menu, flutter, dropdownbutton

I want only 3 items to be visible at a time so that the entire screen doesn't get covered but the options can be even 20. Rest of the options should be visible on scrolling. 
I am able to scroll but the size of list is covering entire screen.

Comment: Share some code

Comment: isDense is for reducing the height, not to fix the length of list as far as I understand.